# Sorting a CSV file

Tags: c#, sorting, csv, alphabetical

so I read a CSV file into C# and did certain manipulations to it, with the final file being named: retainedLines, of type "var". Before I write this file to my hard drive, I want to sort the second column of it. I tried the example at : 
[Sorting csv file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16878467/sorting-csv-file)
but it wouldn't work, I get a handling error instead.
This is the part of my code I am stuck on:

```
String inputpath = textBox1.Text;

if (File.Exists(inputpath))
{
    //MessageBox.Show(inputpath, outputpath);    
    var retainedLines = File.ReadAllLines(inputpath)
        .Where((x, i) => i == 0 
            || (x.Split(',')[1]).Contains(checkCritical())
            || (x.Split(',')[1]).Contains(checkWarning())
            || (x.Split(',')[1]).Contains(checkMajor())
            || (x.Split(',')[1]).Contains(checkClear())       
            );

    if (inputpath.Equals(outputpath))
    {
        File.Delete(inputpath);
    }

    //here is where I want to sort the file alphabetically by second column
    File.WriteAllLines(outputpath, retainedLines);
}
```

Comment: How can a file be of `var` type? Moreover, var is not even a type. Also, you cannot tell us you're getting error, not specifying what error is it.

Comment: LINQ is a solution here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the sorting like this:

```
retainedLines = retainedLines.OrderBy(line => line.Split(',')[1]);
```

But I would refactor the first code so it wouldn't call `Split` method on every time for filtering, instead:

```
var retainedLines = File.ReadAllLines(inputpath)
    .Select(x => x.Split(','))
    .Where((x, i) => i == 0 
        || (x[1]).Contains(checkCritical())
        || (x[1]).Contains(checkWarning())
        || (x[1]).Contains(checkMajor())
        || (x[1]).Contains(checkClear())       
        )
    .OrderBy(x => x[1])
    .Select(parts => string.Join(",", parts);
```